# Grammaticalité de « il y a <nom> d'<adjectif> »

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, oral, attributs

Un exemple de grammaticalité écologique ? Citation de [Jean-Vincent Placé](http://petites-phrases.com/2011/09/25/jean-vincent-place/) :

> Ce soir il y a 10 écologistes d'élus, et c'est une grande joie pour les écologistes.

En quoi cette phrase est-elle non grammaticalement correcte ? Et d'où vient cette construction, qui est relativement courante dans la langue parlée ?

Comment: « Non grammaticalement correct » est-il grammaticalement correct ?

Comment: @Joubarc Oui (j'avais le _bon usage_ sous la main, j'ai vérifié).

Comment: S'il existait une ville du nom d'Élus, ta phrase le serait.

Comment: Voir aussi [son imbécile de frère](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/comment-sappelle-cette-tournure-de-phrase/1706)

Comment: "Une de perdue, dix de retrouvées"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Élus* est ici un attribut d'*écologistes*.  Grevisse dit (j'ai coupé les exemples) :

> L'adjectif  et surtout le participe passé qui accompagnent, comme attributs du « sujet réel », *il y a*, *il est*, *il reste*, *il se trouve*, peuvent être introduits par *de*, notamment quand le nom sujet réel est accompagné d'une indication de quantité (article indéfini, numéral, déterminant indéfini). Ce tour est fréquent dans la langue parlée ; il n'a rien d'incorrect ; et se trouve d'ailleurs parfois dans l'écrit.
>
> Cette contruction apparaît aussi avec *c'est* suivi d'un sujet annoncé par *ce*, puis d'un adjectif ou d'un participe, ainsi qu'avec l'attribut du complément d'objet direct notamment des verbes ***avoir***, *posséder*, *voir*, *rencontrer*, *connaître*, etc., — avec l'attribut des compléments de *voici* et *voilà*, avec des attributs de phrases averbales.
>
> Dans les cas examinés ci-dessus, le *de* n'est pas obligatoire.
>
> Le *de* est très fréquent quand l'expression comporte le pronom en.
>
> Le *de* est obligatoire  : 1<sup>o</sup> quand l'adjectif attribut précède son sujet et que le verbe est construit avec *ne* ... *que* ; 2<sup>o</sup> quand l'ajectif se rapporte à *quelqu'un*, *quelque chose*, *personne*, *rien*, à *que* relatif, à *que*, *quoi* interrogatifs_, à *ceci*, *cela*.

Dans la partie historique il indique que ce *de* a peut-être pour objectif de distinguer un adjectif ou un participe épithète (et donc non essentiel) d'un adjectif ou participe attribut (et donc essentiel à la phrase).

Comment: Donc pour toi la phrase est correcte ? Il me semblait que la question sous-entendait le contraire.

Comment: Oui (bien que l'exemple le plus proche se trouve dans la section « le _de_ n'est pas obligatoire » et donc n'a pas de _de_.).

Comment: Comme exemple, il y a aussi le classique « [Une de perdue, dix de retrouvées](http://www.linternaute.com/proverbe/59/un-de-perdu-dix-de-retrouves/) ». Peut-être y a-t-il une autre faute, alors?

Comment: Pour moi ce dicton est un exemple de la catégorie _attributs de phrases averbales_. Je n'ai simplement pas vu d'exemples chez Grevisse avec _avoir_ conjugué personnellement, mais il donne moins d'exemples que de cas d'utilisation.