# « Son imbécile de mari » : comment s'appelle cette tournure de phrase ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, noms, ordre-des-mots, constructions

Les expressions du style :

- *Son imbécile de frère*
- *Son président de mari*

ont-elles un nom ?

Et quelle est la fonction de chaque mot ?

Comment: Le deuxième mot ("imbécile", "président") est utilisé pour qualifier la chose (ici une personne: "frère", "mari").

Comment: @Otiel Well, duh.

Comment: Et maintenant que j'ai répondu à la question, je me rends compte qu'elle avait déjà été plus ou moins posée posée: [grammaticalité de la tournure <nom> d'<adjectif>](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/grammaticalite-de-il-y-a-nom-dadjectif)

Comment: Merci pour le vote négatif, on peut savoir pourquoi ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait un terme défini.

Le Trésor de la Langue Française précise que *de* est dans ce cas utilisé **après un subst. qualificatif antéposé à valeur adjectivale expressive.**
C'est un **gallicisme** (une particularité de la langue française) où *de* est utilisé pour introduire un **attribut du sujet**. (voir aussi [What is the use of “de” here?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/what-is-the-use-of-de-here/1672#1672))
Ce rôle est habituellement joué par le verbe être (*son frère est un imbécile*)

Le dictionnaire de l'Académie de 1798 [indique](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=de)

> *de* sert quelquefois à lier un substantif avec un adjectif, et forme alors une espèce de gallicisme. *Un fripon d'enfant; un drôle de corps; une coquine de femme.*

Le Trésor de l'a langue français est plus précis, pour l'usage de **de + attribut**

1. **De + attribut du suj.**

   1. [après un subst. qualificatif antéposé à valeur adjectivale expressive.] *Un amour d'enfant, ce fripon de valet; un pauvre diable d'honnête homme; ce grand frisé de Nantais. La, si, do, ré, gredin de ré, va!* (Murger, Scènes vie boh., 1851, p. 17). *M. de Brécé doit le bouton à ce bon petit voisin d'Ernest* (A. France, Anneau améth., 1899, p. 131).
   2. [après un adj. ou subst. qualificatif antéposé et le plus souvent déterminé.] *Un drôle de bruit; chienne de vie! coquin de sort! cette canaille d'oncle! son diable de chapeau à la main :*
      Rem. Certains tours sont vivants en fr. parlé, pop. ou vulgaire.

      > J'étais bien plus isolé qu'un naufragé sur un radeau au milieu de l'Océan. Alors vous imaginez ma surprise, au lever du jour, quand une drôle de petite voix m'a réveillé. Elle disait : − S'il vous plaît... Dessine-moi un mouton!
      >   (Saint-Exupéry, Le Petit Prince, 1943, p. 413.)
   3. dans le gallicisme vieilli *si j'étais (que) de vous*.
   4. Pauvre de moi! Pauvres de nous! (loc. d'orig. provençale) :

      > Pauvre de moi! disait-il [maître Cornille]. Maintenant, je n'ai plus qu'à mourir... Le moulin est déshonoré. (A. Daudet, Lettres de mon moulin, 1869, p. 28.)
   5. NB J'ai supprimé d'autres exemples, voir le [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)
2. **de + attribut du compl. d'obj. dir.** après des verbes comme traiter, qualifier, taxer, accuser; gratifier (qqn, qqc.) de.

   > Après avoir lu les secrètes infortunes du père Goriot, vous dînerez avec appétit en mettant votre insensibilité sur le compte de l'auteur, en le taxant d'exagération, en l'accusant de poésie.
   >   (Balzac, Le Père Goriot, 1835, p. 6.)

Comment: Et pour fournir une réponse claire: _imbécile_ est un substantif qualificatif antéposé à valeur adjectivale expressive ; _frère_ est nom attribut du sujet ; et la tournure globale n'a pas de nom, mais fait partie des gallicismes.

Answer (score 4):

Voici mon explication :

Les tournures de ce genre ont pour but de mettre l'accent sur les mots décrivant le sujet de la phrase, plutôt que sur le sujet lui-même. En employant la tournure « mon imbécile de frère » plutôt que « mon frère imbécile », *imbécile* devient alors le mot « central » de la phrase et donne un impact plus fort au qualificatif du sujet, plutôt qu'au sujet lui-même. On comprend alors que, du point de vue du narrateur, à ce moment précis, la relation familiale avec « le frère » est beaucoup moins importante que son niveau d'intelligence.

<sub>(J'invite les gens à me corriger si certains des termes que j'emploie ne sont pas exacts ou corrects.)</sub>

Comment: Explication intéressante, mais la question principale porte sur le nom de cette tournure de phrase, s'il y en a un, evidemment.

Comment: Merci @Laure pour les corrections :)