# What is the use of “de” in “mon but est de”?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

What's the difference between these two sentences:

1. Mon but est faire le bien autour de moi.
2. Mon but est de faire le bien autour de moi.

Comment: The sentence without *de* is ungrammatical. I'm hard-pressed to explain why.

Comment: @Gilles Je tente l'explication par le groupe prépositionnel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that situation, *de* is used to build a prepositional group (*de faire le bien autour de moi*).

This prepositional group is the attribute of the subject.
There are different kinds of constructions for the attribute of the subject:

- adjective: *mon but est noble*
- noun: *mon but est un objectif difficile*
- pronoun: *mon but est uniquement le mien*
- prepositional group of the form "de {infinitive}": *mon but est de répondre à cette question*
- past particple: *mon but est atteint*
- proposition introduced by *que*: *mon but est que tu viennes ce soir*

Answer (score 2):

In the second sentence the "de" has the same role than the "to" when you say

> My goal is **to** do ...

The first sentence is wrong.
It would be similar than saying in English:

> My goal is do good things ....

Comment: Except that infinitive is introduced by the particle "to" in English. I'm sure you would not translate _je veux faire ceci_ by _I want do this_.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [*Banque de dépannage linguistique*](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4217), it is a pecularity of the infinitive phrases that are arguments of *être* if the subject is not an infinitive itself : such constructions have to begin by *de*. I'd have a hard time trying to derive a general rule from this

> L'infinitif en fonction attribut est précédé de la préposition de lorsque le sujet n'est pas un autre verbe à l'infinitif et qu'il est repris par une expression comme c'est ou ce serait.