# Inversion des rôles entre le nom et l'adjectif : d'où vient et comment s'appelle cette construction?

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots, constructions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment s’appelle cette tournure de phrase ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/comment-sappelle-cette-tournure-de-phrase)

Je n'ai pas voulu choisir un exemple arbitraire pour la formulation même de la question, mais en voici un :

> Elle est venue avec *son imbécile de mari*.

Il me semble que la construction la plus simple pour dire la même chose serait : *Elle est venue avec son mari imbécile*, dans la mesure où *mari* est bien le nom commun principal, et que l'adjectif *imbécile* vient le qualifier. Mais dans mon exemple initial, les rôles s'inversent, *imbécile* devient le coeur du groupe nominal et le (théorique) nom commun principal se transforme en complément du nom (*... de mari*).

On rencontre (assez) couramment cette forme (apportant souvent une touche d'ironie). Pourquoi? (et depuis quand?) Et comment ça s'appelle?

Comment: Doublon possible: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/comment-sappelle-cette-tournure-de-phrase, et question reliée: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/grammaticalite-de-il-y-a-nom-dadjectif.

Comment: Ah merci ! C'est juste, je n'avais pas trouvé ces questions similaires. Parfait, je vais aller voir ça.